# Parsing through JSON and selecting multiple items in java

Tags: java, json, gson

I currently have this JSON:

```
[ 
    {
        "example": "12345678",
        "test": "0",
        "name": "tom",
        "testdata": "",
        "testtime": 1531209885613   
    },   
    {
        "example": "12634346",
        "test": "43223452234",
        "name": "jerry",
        "testdata": "pawenkls",
        "testtime": 1531209888196   
    }   
]
```

I am trying to parse through the array to find a value of "testdata" that matches the value of "testdata" that I have generated, which I am currently doing like so:

```
JsonArray entries = (JsonArray) new JsonParser().parse(blockchainJson);
JsonElement dataHash = ((JsonObject)entries.get(i)).get("dataHash");
```

Then I wish to find the value of "example" that is in the same array as the "testdata" with the value "pawenkls".

How do I search for the "example" value that is in the same group as the value of "test data" that I have found?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run through the objects in the array and check the value of the `testData` field against yours. Then read its `example` field.

```
String testData = "pawenkls";

JsonArray entries = (JsonArray) new JsonParser().parse(blockchainJson);
String example = null;
for(JsonElement dataHashElement : entries) {
    JsonObject currentObject = dataHashElement.getAsJsonObject();
    if(testData.equals(currentObject.get("testdata").getAsString())) {
        example = currentObject.get("example").getAsString();
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println("example: "+example);
```

This prints out

```
example: 12634346
```

Here is a Java 8 version doing the same thing:

```
String testData = "pawenkls";

JsonObject[] objects = new Gson().fromJson(blockchainJson, JsonObject[].class);
Optional<JsonObject> object = Arrays.stream(objects)
    .filter(o -> testData.equals(o.get("testdata").getAsString()))
    .findFirst();

String example = null;
if(object.isPresent())
    example = object.get().get("example").getAsString();

System.out.println("example: "+example);
```